# something equivalent to 'pinchstart' in hammer js? changing height of div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hammer.js

I am creating a cordova app in the `ionic` framework which uses `hammer.js` gestures

When you use the `drag` gesture there are corresponding `dragstart` and `dragend` gestures which capture the start and end of a drag in addition to the actual dragging. This is useful because sometimes you need to know the information at `drag start`.

I don't see an equivalent for `pinch` gesture, but is there something else that can be done to obtain this information?

I am using `pinch` to change the height of a div.

My problem is that, if I don't know the height at the start of a pinch, then the only height I know is the current height. And since I'm changing the height with the pinch, this has an exponential effect on the height and it changes quite quickly. (example 1 below)

If I change the height with `e.gesture.scale` and set height as a %, then I don't know the height of the div if someone were to stop pinching and restart later. This has the visual effect of starting the pinch at 100% again, and this is quite jarring on the eyes. (example 2 below)

---

**example 1 problem:**  height changes exponentially because only height I have changes with the pinch

`height = e.gesture.startEvent.target.offsetHeight * e.gesture.scale + "px"`

Not sure why `e.gesture.startEvent.target.offsetHeight` changes, I assumed it was constant but it is not.

**example 2 problem:** On a second pinch it is jarring on the eyes because the initial height always starts at 100% even if the pinch already scaled the div down.

`height = e.gesture.scale*100 +"%"`

---

**Ideal scenario**
If I had the height at the start of a pinch I could do something like:

`height = pinchStartHeight*e.gesture.scale + "px"`

which would make it scale perfectly since `pinchStartHeight` would presumably be constant.

Any `pinchStart` equivalents or anything that might lead me to a solution on my problem?

Answer (score 1):

A `pinchstart` event is defined [here in the HammerJS documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pinch/).
I usually store (in a variable) scale (and also translate) values on touch end because in hammerJS those values always refer to current gesture.